# Cómo hago para saber si se permitió o se rechazó el acceso a la ubicación

Tags: javascript, geolocation-api

Estoy solicitando el permiso del usuario para obtener su ubicación pero no sé cómo saber si la permitió o se encuentra denegada... Y que sea compatible con webview de Android ya que es una webapp.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((uj) => {
    
    console.log(uj.coords.latitude + uj.coords.longitude);
    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El segundo argumento de la función `getCurrentPosition` es otra función (callback) que se ejecuta cuando no es posible obtener la posición.

Ejemplo

```js
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(uj => {
    console.log(uj.coords.latitude + uj.coords.longitude); 
},error);

function error(err) {
  console.error(err.message);
}
```